# Как выделить определенную ячейку цветом

Tags: excel

Допустим, в одной колонке содержатся разные адреса e-mail, мне нужно выделить все адреса желтым цветом - у кого e-mail = @gmail.com. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделяете диапазон ячеек в которых нужно изменить цвет (там где у вас адреса). Далее <kbd>Главная</kbd> - <kbd>Условное форматирование</kbd> - <kbd>Правила выделения ячеек</kbd> - <kbd>Текст содержит ...</kbd>  в открывшемся окне пишите текст, который обязательно должен быть в ячейке (в вашем случае gmail.com). Устанавливаете цвет, каким будет закрашиваться ячейка

Comment: спасибо @MaximK !!! то что нужно :)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте "Условное форматирование -> Новое правило".
Там задайте диапазоны форматирования и условия.

Answer (score 0):

**Для случаев, когда нужно оперативно просматривать данные при разных искомых значениях.**

Диапазон форматирования - столбец *А*. Отдельная ячейка для критерия - *B2*

Выделить столбец *А*, закладка *Главная-Условное_форматирование-Создать_правило-Использовать_формулу*

```
=ПОИСК($B$2;A1)
```

Задать нужный формат (заливку).

Некоторые знаки в *Excel* зарезервированы под служебные. Например, если искомый текст будет начинаться на *=*, *+*, *@*, текст будет воспринят как формула, функция. Во избежание недоразумений формат ячейки *В2* задать текстовым.

```
' -----------------
```

Условное форматирование грузит файл, при наличии многих условий в УФ взможно подтормаживание при изменении данных. Облегчить можно  **с помощью VBA** (макрос).

Использовать просто.

*Alt+F11* - вход в редактор VBA

Вкладка *Insert-Module* - создание общего модуля.

Раскрыть модуль и разместить там код, показанный ниже.

На листе можно создать кнопку (например, *Вставка-Фигуры*), которой присвоить запуск макроса (*ПКМ-Назначить_макрос*).

```
' заливка ячеек столбца А, содержащих искомый фрагмент (ячейкa В2)
Sub SearchOfText()
Dim ArrData()
Dim rRng As Range
Dim sStr As String
Dim lRws As Long, i As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' последняя заполненная ячейка
        If lRws < 2 Then Exit Sub ' данных нет (первая строка - шапка таблицы)
        ArrData = Range("A1:A" & lRws).Value ' значения столбца А в массив
        sStr = .Range("B2").Value ' искомый фрагмент в переменную

        For i = 2 To lRws ' циклом по массиву
            If ArrData(i, 1) Like "*" & sStr & "*" Then ' искомый фрагмент в тексте есть
                If rRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rRng = .Cells(i, 1) ' формируем диапазон
                Else
                    Set rRng = Union(rRng, .Cells(i, 1)) 'пополняем диапазон
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' отключаем обновление экрана
        .Range("A2:A" & lRws).Interior.Pattern = xlNone ' удаление предыдущей заливки
        If Not rRng Is Nothing Then rRng.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 ' красим диапазон
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' включаем обновление экрана
    End With

    Set rRng = Nothing ' освобождаем память
End Sub
```

Comment: спасибо! @vikttur

Comment: Для коллекции макрос добавить? )

Comment: :D :D спасибо, но я не умею ими пользоваться :)